# I am trying to sort a single linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

My code is working so wrong! After entering and sorting some numbers of list, for some numbers it doesn't work and deletes older node or doesn't show them. Couldn't get what's wrong.

Sometimes it looks like it is working fine, for example : I entered 4, 6, 7, 2 and it showed truly in the sorted list. but after entering 3 it didn't show 3 in the list.

Here is my code:

```
if(head == NULL)     
{
    head = info;    
    last = info;
    info->next = NULL;   
}
else  
{
    if(info->number > last->number)  
    {
        last->next = info;  
        last = info;            
        info->next = NULL;  
    }
    else if (info->number < head->number ) 
    {          
        info -> next = head;       
        head = info;            
    }

    prev = head;

    for(temp = head-> next ; temp!= NULL; temp = temp->next) 
    {
        prev = prev->next;
        if(info->number >temp->number)
        {
            temp->next = info;                          
        }
        else
        {
            temp-> prev = info;
            info = prev;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Debugging is a skill that you need to learn.  Best to start now.  Set a break point and start stepping through your code to see how you've failed your assumptions.  I'd expect to see a linked list ADT and a separate sort method.  I can't tell if it's your list that's bad or the sort implementation.

Comment: @Nodeum I think it is better to use insertion sort for lists.

Comment: I never use debugging before but it's time to use thanks @Vlad from Moscow I just wanted to use  my own algorthm but it seems it doesn't work, thanks for advice.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow : I think it is even better to use mergesort for linked lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(head == NULL)     
{
    head = info;    
    last = info;

    info->next = NULL;   
}
else  
{
    if(info->number >= last->number)  <-- CHANGE:: > changed to >= to take care of same number (as earlier stored number) being entered
    {
        last->next = info;  
        last = info;            
        info->next = NULL;
        return;  <-- CHANGE:return added here, no need to proceed further
    }
    else if (info->number <= head->number) <-- CHANGE:: < changed to <= to take care of same number (as earlier stored number) being entered
    {         
        info -> next = head;       
        head = info;
        return; <-- CHANGE:return added here, no need to proceed further
    }

    prev = head;

    for(temp = head->next ; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next) 
    {
        if(temp->number >= info->number)  <-- CHANGE: modified code when insertion happens between head and last
        {
            prev->next = info;
            info->next = temp;
            break;
        }

        prev = temp;
    }
}
```

In your original code, the final else case:

```
 else
 {
    temp-> prev = info;
    info = prev;
 }
```

This code is not making any sense since you mentioned singly linked list, but here you have used 'temp->prev'.

Definitely, there is scope for code size reduction in your code (if and else-if  check can be removed and directly 'for' loop executed to insert the new element)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(head == NULL)     
{
    head = info;    
    last = info;
    info->next = NULL;
    last=info; 
}
else  
{
    if(info->number>head->number){
        info->next=head;
        head = info;    
     }
    else{
        tmp=prev=head;
        while(tmp && (info->number < tmp->number)  )
        {
            prev=tmp;
            tmp=tmp->next;
        }

        info->next=prev->next;
        prev->next=info;

        if(!tmp) last=info;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider building it as an array, sorting the array, and using it from there.

Comment: This more a comment then an Answer.

Comment: I consider it more of an answer.  If you have a requirement that the container be in order then a linked list is probably the wrong kind of container to use..   One can implement a linked list sort of structure using an array.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a bubble sort, which is not the quickest way to sort.

Fortunately, your C library is very likely to provide an efficient quick-sort algorithm (`qsort`). To use this with a linked list:

- Allocate (using `malloc`) and array of pointers of size equal to the number of items in the linked list.
- Traverse the linked list, making each entry of the array point to an item in the linked list
- Sort the pointers using `qsort` and a specified comparison routine
- Iterate through the array, setting each element's previous and next pointer as appropriate (i.e. ignore the previous linkages totally).
- Free the array

This is almost always quicker that swapping the actual element's `next` and `prev` pointers around, and less error prone.

If you insist on using your bubble sort, you can simply replace the third step by your bubble sort.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sorting a "single linked list" You are trying to keep the list sorted as the user provides input. In addition the list you are working on does not look like a single linked list. It has both "next" and "prev" pointers, so it should be a "double linked list".

Start with implementing a single list adding the items to the end. With a little tweak, you can keep it sorted. Don't go to the end of the list every time you want to add an item, but rather find the first item in the list that is greater or equal to the item you want to add, and insert your new item just before it. If you can't find such an item, you are at the end. Your item will be the greater. Just add it to the end.